# How To resample one 'Date' column Without Altering the Other Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, resampling

I'm trying to resample just one column in my DF , without altering the other , so here's the desired output:

```
    Sensor_ID   Time_Instant    Measurement
0    14121    2013/11/14 00:00:00     0.8
1    14121    2013/11/14 03:00:00     0.6
2    14121    2013/11/14 06:00:00     0.4
3    14121    2013/11/14 09:00:00     0.4
4    14121    2013/11/14 12:00:00      0
```

Here's What I actually Have :

```
    Sensor_ID   Time_Instant    Measurement
0    14121    2013/11/14 17:00    0.8
1    14121    2013/11/14 18:00    0.6
2    14121    2013/11/14 19:00    0.4
3    14121    2013/11/14 20:00    0.4
4    14121    2013/11/14 21:00     0
```

Here's My attemp:

```
Mi_Meteo.columns = pd.to_datetime(Mi_Meteo.columns ,errors='coerce' ) 
Mi_Meteo.resample('3H', on='Time_Instant').sum()
```

But I get This Error:

```
'The grouper name Time_Instant is not found'
```

Any Suggestion ? , Thank U.

Comment: Do you want to _replace_ the current times with the 3H increments, or do you have all of them and just want to _downsample_?

Comment: Well I want to to downsample the current time as i mentioned in the first DF with the date and the 3 hours range , but keeping the two other columns (Sensor_ID , Measurement) untouched

Comment: What about something like `df['Time_Instant'] = df.set_index('Time_Instant').resample('3H').count().index`? You might need to pad with `NaN`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you simply want to pull the times up (downsampling) without affecting the other values. If so you will need to pad the new times at the end. I used `NaN`s. Once the lengths are the same you can replace your original column.

```
import numpy as np 

new = df.set_index('Time_Instant').resample('3H').count().index
df['Time_Instant'] = np.pad(new, (0,len(df) - len(new)), 'constant', 
                            constant_values=(0,np.nan))
```

Comment: The Thing is i'm still Having this Error.                                  KeyError : 'Time_Instant'

Comment: what are the exact names of your columns? if you type `df.columns`?

Comment: This is what I get : Index(['Sensor_ID', 'Time_Instant', 'Measurement'], dtype='object')